# jquery ajax passing information using load

Tags: jquery

I have an associative array and I'm trying to pass it to the parameters section of the jquery load method.  However it is not showing up as a post on the server side.  How can I accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
var selectcustomerpopup = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Find customer
    $('.CustomerSelectBtn').click(function() {
        var uniqueid = $(this).attr('id');

        var customerSelectURL = $('#ajax_customer_select_url').val() 
                   + "/" + uniqueid;
        var custselectdata = new Array();

        custselectdata["fname"] = "TestFirst";
        custselectdata["lname"] = "TestLast";

        if (! ($('#selectCustomerDialog').length)) {
          $('body').append(
              $('<div id="selectCustomerDialog" style="display: none;"></div>')
               );
        }

        var $findCustomerDialog = 
              $('#selectCustomerDialog').load
               (customerSelectURL, custselectdata)
            .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Customer',
            width: 630,
            height: 450,
            position: 'center', 
            resizeable: true,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeText: 'close'

        });
        $findCustomerDialog.dialog('open');
        selectcustomerpopup = $findCustomerDialog;
        return false;
    });
  } );
```

Additional Info:
I got a good answer, but I did some more research and found a great link explaining associative arrays in javascript very well: http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/

Comment: I think you need only to replace the `custselectdata` array with an object: `var custselectdata = {};`

Comment: mblase, you had the correct answer, replacing the array with {} to make it an object was the solution that worked, but there is no answer for me to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have true associative arrays.  You only need to replace the `custselectdata` array with an object: `var custselectdata = {};`

Comment: it might not be considered a true associative array, but it looks and acts like an associative array to me. If I can just figure out how to loop though the elements, I'll have everything I need.

Comment: @stephenbayer  Yes, this is true. I just meant that you can't declare it as an array; you need to declare an object which then behaves exactly like an associative array. Looping through it can then be done using `for (key in object) {...}` and values can be obtained with something like `var val = object[key];`

Answer (score 0):

The data needs to be formatted as a string:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

So you could do:

```
var custSelectData = "fname=TestFirst&lname=TestLast";
```

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be a string. A map of the data would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `custselectdata` var for

```
var custselectdata = {fname: 'testfirst', lname: 'testlast'};
```